# How to output the full path of a FilePathField in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Consider the following model:

```
STOCK_IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'stock_images')

class Product(models.Model):
    stock_image = models.FilePathField(path=STOCK_IMAGE_DIR, default='image.png')
```

When accessing the `stock_image` of a product, it only returns the name of the image:

```
>>> p = Product.objects.first()
>>> p.stock_image
'image.png'
```

How can I output the *entire* path of the file?

Comment: I would advice to use a `FileFIeld` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield) over a `FilePathField`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
p = Product.objects.first()
print(os.path.join(Product._meta.get_field('stock_image').path, p.stock_image))
```

Or

```
print(os.path.join(STOCK_IMAGE_DIR, p.stock_image))
```

Or, if you store the path in the class you can add a property for getting the full path

```
class Product(models.Model):

    STOCK_IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'stock_images')

    stock_image = models.FilePathField(path=STOCK_IMAGE_DIR, default='image.png')

    @property
    def stock_image_path(self):
        return os.path.join(self.STOCK_IMAGE_DIR, self.stock_image)
```

Then you can just use the property

```
p = Product.objects.first()
print(p.stock_image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this sure seems messy.  It seems like it defeats the purpose of `FilePathField`.

Comment: I agree, it's messy. I don't think this field is used very often and so is a little under-developed

Comment: Probably better to store the path on the class/model so that you can reference it easier

Comment: @ReinstateMonica updated the answer with a nicer solution I think

Answer (score 1):

While [@IainShelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59523850/67579) provides a solution to obtain the path, you might want to use a [**`FileField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield), or if you work with images, like the name `stock_image` suggests, with an [**`ImageField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).

If you model this like:

```
STOCK_IMAGE_DIR = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'stock_images')

class Product(models.Model):
    stock_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=STOCK_IMAGE_DIR, default='image.png')
```

then the `some_product.stock_image` will be an [**`ImageFieldFile`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L349-L354). This is an object that mimics a `File`, and has for example a `path` attribute to obtain the path where the file is stored:

```
some_product.stock_image.path
```

Furthermore a `FileField` and `ImageField` make it more convenient to work with forms where you *upload* images, and furthermore these have a `.url` attribute to obtain the URL such that the server can serve media files.